# How to create sprites using ConfigParser in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a Pygame program and I cant get sprites to work.

I am using ConfigParser and the map for my proof of concept is:

```
##################
##################
#...#########....#
#.p.........#....#
#...#######....p.#
###########.#....#
##.p.######.#....#
##...######.######
###.#######.######
###.............##
###############.##
######.p.######.##
######...#####..##
######...#.....###
#######.##...#####
##..........######
##.######...######
#...#####...######
#.p.#####..#######
#...#####..#######
#########..#######
```

where p is a sprite

how would I tell ConfigParser that if there is a p it is a sprite?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you read it as normal text file. And so you will have to draw sprite on your own - ConfigParser can't do this for you.

Comment: how would you do that? can you put an example in as an answer @furas

Comment: You could use ConfigParser to read in the map data (or just do  as @furas suggests). Either way, you will have to write additional code to parse the character data and draw sprites at the proper place whenever a `'p'` character is encountered. To get started just hardcode the character map data into your script. Once that is working you can add obtaining it from an external source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# load map

mymap = []

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        mymap.append( line.strip() )

# show map

for line in mymap:
    print line

# find sprites on map

for y, line in enumerate(mymap):
    for x, char in enumerate(line):
        if char == 'p':
            print 'sprite at', x, y
```

Result:

```
##################
##################
#...#########....#
#.p.........#....#
#...#######....p.#
###########.#....#
##.p.######.#....#
##...######.######
###.#######.######
###.............##
###############.##
######.p.######.##
######...#####..##
######...#.....###
#######.##...#####
##..........######
##.######...######
#...#####...######
#.p.#####..#######
#...#####..#######
#########..#######

sprite at 2 3
sprite at 15 4
sprite at 3 6
sprite at 7 11
sprite at 2 18
```

You can read it also this way:

```
mymap = open('data.txt').readlines()
mymap = map(str.strip,mymap) # to remove '\n'
```

Comment: thank you, that code works perfectly, but last thing (I promise), how do I tell it to display the sprites at those locations?

Comment: In pygame you need to do it on your own - get location (recalculate to x,y on screen) and use [blit()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) or [pygame.draw](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html)

Comment: Thank you all the code works fine, it just says there is way more sprites than I have on the map, but ill figure it out, it may just be wrapping weirdly. Thanks @furas